# Extracting sublists in a nested list in Python

Tags: python, list, boolean-expression

Given the a string like: '~a & ~b & (~c | ~a) -> c'

I wish to generate a list containing all the sub-statements of this statement, namely:

```
- (~c|~a)
- ~a & ~b & (~c | ~a)
- ~a & ~b & (~c | ~a) -> c
```

into a list. I already have a parser that is able to find:

```
- [[['~', 'a', '&', '~', 'b', '&', ['~', 'c', '|', '~', 'a']], '@', 'c']]
```

From here I wish to condense each list into its own statement sequentially and evaluate each of them as sub-list, namely I want to find in the list above:

```
- ['~', 'c', '|', '~', 'a']
- ['~', 'a', '&', '~', 'b', '&', ['~', 'c', '|', '~', 'a']]
- [[['~', 'a', '&', '~', 'b', '&', ['~', 'c', '|', '~', 'a']], '@', 'c']]
```

Could anyone give me advice on how to accomplish this? I want to do so recursively, but I have not been able to come up with a solution.

My overall goal is to make a boolean expression evaluator, so if anyone has guidance on that as well it would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't parse this into a tree? A common approach is to convert into a variant which serializes into RPN, i.e. the root of each expression is the operator, and the branches are the operands.

Comment: This was just the first thing I thought of, do you have an example or resource I could look at for what you're talking about?

Comment: Googling for [python recursive-descent](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20recursive-descent) seems to got me some reasonably promising hits.

Comment: I think your expression summarizes to `~(A|B) = ~A&~B`. Why don't just go straight to the result of ~(A|B)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily this is a pretty easy recursion to set up:

```
x = [[['~', 'a', '&', '~', 'b', '&', ['~', 'c', '|', '~', 'a']], '@', 'c']]

def sublists(outerlist):
    ret = []
    for x in outerlist:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            ret.append(x)
            ret.extend(sublists(x))
    return ret

print "\n".join("{0}".format(l) for l in sublists(x))
```

This prints:

```
[['~', 'a', '&', '~', 'b', '&', ['~', 'c', '|', '~', 'a']], '@', 'c']
['~', 'a', '&', '~', 'b', '&', ['~', 'c', '|', '~', 'a']]
['~', 'c', '|', '~', 'a']
```

Comment: I figured it was something like this, but I haven't quite mastered recursion, and was running into a lot of walls. Thanks so much.

Comment: Could you explain what the 'ret.extend(sublists(x))' is doing?

Comment: .extend() is like .append(), but it takes a list and appends all the values to the list, rather than putting a single value there. So whenever we find a list, we append it to our array, then we ask it if **it** has any sublists, and extend our array with the results.  If the sublist doesn't have any, it'll just return an empty list, so .extend() is a no-op, which is fine.